# How to watch a variable in a Service from a Controller to open a modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

**http://plnkr.co/edit/bdHiU0?p=preview**

---

If the variable I need is some data that the service returns I'm fine, something like this will work:

`vm.tickersObject = InitTickersFactory.returnTickers();`

However in the plnkr example above I'm just setting a toggle variable in my `tickerController` which then passes and stores the value into the `AddTickerFactory`.

Click the **open modal** button to see the logs.

Now I need my `tickerModalController` to get that variable and then display or hide a modal. However `vs.showModal` in my `tickerModalController` stays stuck as `false`:

`vs.showModal = AddTickerFactory.getToggleStatus();`

#### Markup

```
<ticker-modal></ticker-modal>
<tickers-panel></tickers-panel>
```

#### Full code

```
// Code goes here

angular.module('app', [])

.directive('tickersPanel', function() {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
      // console.debug($scope, attrs);
    },
    template: '<div class="ticker" ng-controller="tickerController"><button ng-click="openModal()">Open Modal</button></div>'
  };
})

.directive('tickerModal', function() {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
      // console.debug($scope, attrs);
    },
    template: '<div class="modal" ng-show="showModal" ng-controller="tickerModalController"><h1>Hello World!</h1></div>'
  };
})

.factory('AddTickerFactory', [function() {
    var vm = this;
        vm.addTickerToggle = false;

    var addTicker = {
        toggleAddTicker : toggleAddTicker,
        getToggleStatus : getToggleStatus
    }

    return addTicker;

    function toggleAddTicker(bool) {
      console.log(bool);
      vm.addTickerToggle = bool;
    }

    function getToggleStatus() {
        return vm.addTickerToggle;
    }
}])

.controller('tickerController', 
  ['$scope',
   'AddTickerFactory',
   function($scope,
            AddTickerFactory) {

  var vs = $scope;
      vs.addTicker = false;

  vs.openModal = openModal;

  function openModal() {
        vs.addTicker = !vs.addTicker;
        AddTickerFactory.toggleAddTicker(vs.addTicker);
  }
}])

.controller('tickerModalController', 
  ['$scope',
   'AddTickerFactory',
   function($scope,
            AddTickerFactory) {

  var vs = $scope;
      vs.showModal = false;

  vs.showModal = AddTickerFactory.getToggleStatus();
  console.log('vs.showModal',vs.showModal);

  vs.displayModal = displayModal;

  function displayModal() {
    vs.showModal = !vs.showModal;
  }
}]);
```

---

I tried added a watch, but it shows nothing changing:

```
vs.showModal = AddTickerFactory.getToggleStatus();
console.log('vs.showModal',vs.showModal);

$scope.$watch('vs.showModal', function(current, original) {
    console.log('current',current);
    console.log('original',original);
});
```

Comment: well .. you're not actually opening the modal anywhere ... so that code won't ever execute unless you call $modal.open(...)

Comment: @sirrocco that is what I'm trying to do, the modal directive is separate from the directive with the button. I hit a button and change the toggle which then needs to open the modal. How do I pass that variable into the directive in the above code? I know I use a Service, but no luck at the moment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$watch` also takes a function so you could have :

http://plnkr.co/edit/oJ2CTVXKCiLwL9oNw6YR?p=preview

```
  $scope.$watch(function(){
    return AddTickerFactory.getToggleStatus();
  }, function(current, original) {
    vs.showModal = current;
      console.log('current',current);
      console.log('original',original);
  });
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Would you know what the performance of using `$watch` vs `$emit` and `$broadcast` is? I have a lot of modals in my app and wondering which is more efficient...

Comment: `$broadcast` and `$emit` will be more performant (since `$watch` is evaluated one every `$digest` cycle) but you will probably have to use `$rootScope` for the emit/broadcast.

Comment: I also just found this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2806-creating-a-simple-modal-system-in-angularjs.htm He created a nice light modal service, which uses `broadcast` and some niceties like passing params and using `ngSwitch`

Comment: You can also look at Angular UI as they have a lot of components (a modal service too)